# java.ext.dirs System Property in Java

Tags: java, security, code-access-security

I'm using JDK 1.6 on Windows XP OS. Running a simple Java program to print the value of `java.ext.dirs` System property:

```
System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")
```

prints:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext

Out of the two directory that got printed, the second one does not exists on my system i.e. `C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext` directory is not available in my system.

I'm not understanding, why then Java returns this illegal directory value for `java.ext.dirs`
property?
 And how can i eliminate this value from `java.ext.dirs` property?

Comment: By the way -- move to a system above Windows XP as soon as you can ... Microsoft is no longer providing security patches for this vintage operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not understanding, why then Java returns this illegal directory value for java.ext.dirs property?

It is returning the places that the JVM will look.  If there is a non-existent directory in the list, I'd expect it to be silently ignored.  Are you observing something different?

> And how can i eliminate this value from java.ext.dirs property?

My reading of [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html) is that you should be able to set the property.  (The same page explains how the path is used, and how the default is determined.)

You probably need to set it via the command line; e.g using `-Djava.ext.dirs=...`.  I'd expect changes to the property made after the JVM had bootstrapped to have no effect.

Comment: No, the program run without error, but when I enable the Security Manager (-Djava.security.debug=all -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djava.security.manager), I could see the messages and an exception that 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null KeyStore name at sun.security.util.PolicyUtil.getKeyStore(Unknown Source)' . I have posted the stacktrace above.

Comment: I think that this is something that you don't need to worry about.  And if you are worried, just create the missing directory ... with nothing in it.

Answer (score 2):

Those are directories in which Java will look for extensions. If one of the directories isn't there, no extensions will be found there -- no big deal, why does it matter?

In any case, you can provide `-Djava.ext.dirs=PATH` on the Java command line, if you'd like.

Comment: Actually I was trying to see the log messages by enabling Security Manager in my Java program. My program did not break, but in the log messages I could see below stack trace:

Comment: policy: reading file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/security/java.policy
 [Policy Parser]: creating policy entry for expanded java.ext.dirs path:
  file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/*
 [Policy Parser]: creating policy entry for expanded java.ext.dirs path:
  file:/C:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/lib/ext/*
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null KeyStore name
 at sun.security.util.PolicyUtil.getKeyStore(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.init(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.access$400(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile$3.run(Unknown Sou